# Spring Data 2.0.x AuditorAware getCurrentUser method throws AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement `AuditorAware` into my web application. Below is the list of my library version:

- jsf 2.2.13
- hibername 5.1.3.Final
- spring 5.0.3.RELEASE
- spring-data 2.0.3.RELEASE
- spring-security 5.0.1.RELEASE

This is my persistence config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext
{
     @Bean
     public AuditorAware<AccountModel> auditorAware()
     {
         return new AuditorAwareImpl();
     }
}
```

And this is my AuditorAwareImpl class:

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<AccountModel>
{
    @Override
    public Optional<AccountModel> getCurrentAuditor()
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable((AccountModel) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

AccountModel:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
public class AccountModel extends BaseModel implements UserDetails
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4792614546550769652L;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "accPackage", length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String accPackage;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RoleModel> role = new HashSet<RoleModel>();

    @Transient
    private transient Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
}
```

BaseModel:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseModel implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8027746305948051121L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private AccountModel createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dateCreated", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "modifiedBy", insertable = false)
    private AccountModel modifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dateModified", insertable = false)
    private Date dateModified;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "verCtrl", nullable = false)
    private Integer version;
}
```

When I try to persist an object, AbstractMethodError will be thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.project.core.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.getCurrentAuditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touchAuditor(AuditingHandler.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touch(AuditingHandler.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markCreated(AuditingHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate(AuditingEntityListener.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
    ... 124 more
```

**UPDATE**
After I have changed my Spring Data from 2.x to 1.x, it works, no more exception. I think the problem is with the return data type of the `getCurrentUser()` method. In 1.x, return datatype is simply your custom `UserDetails` object, but in 2.x, the return datatype is `Optional<CustomModel>`. Could it possible be the cause of error?

Comment: Bingo! Your update put me on the right track :-)
My library project  was in spring boot 1.5.4 and that's where I implemented the AuditorAware<T> interface. But it runs in the main application project, and that one is in Spring Boot 2. Time to upgrade the library project to spring boot 2 also.

Comment: @Philippe But I am not using Spring Boot tho, and my Spring version is already the latest which is 5.0.x, so this case I am not sure what library I need to upgrade, in the end I can only downgrade the Spring Data

Comment: have you tried looking at the transitive dependencies? For example if using gradle, you could type `gradle dependencies` to get a tree of transitive dependencies to see what versions of spring are getting mixed.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, cause of this error is change in the return data type of the `getCurrentUser()` method.
In 2.x versions, this is changed to Optional (In 1.x versions, the return type was simply T).
There are two ways to solve this :

1. Downgrade Spring Data from 2.x to 1.x
2. But, as I had to keep Spring Data on 2.x version, I simply changed the code from

   `@Override
   public String getCurrentAuditor() {
       return currentUser();
   }`

   to

   `@Override
   public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
       return Optional.of(currentUser());
   }`